# Examples of curves with A7 symmetries

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to find examples of smooth algebraic curves with a (nontrivial) action of the alternating group $A_7$. Any examples are appreciated, and if there are classical examples, e.g. of genus 31 curves (the minimal genus allowed by the Hurwitz bound), or curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$ analogous to Wiman's planar sextic for $A_6$, that would be even better.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a simple example,  take the curve in $\mathbb{P}^6$ given by $s_1=\cdots =s_5 $, where $s_i$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $i$. It has genus 481. I am sure there are examples of lower genus; you can find probaly some in Breuer's *Characters and Automorphism Groups of Compact Riemann Surfaces*, London Math. Soc. Lecture Notes 280.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Breuer.  The example you gave is the only one I had on hand when I asked the question, but your comment about the genus is helpful.  What is the easiest way to see that the genus is in fact 481?

Comment: Genus $31$ will not be achievable. Recall that a group $G$ acts on a curve of genus $1+|G|/84$ if and only if $G$ can be generated by elements $\rho$,  $\sigma$ and $\tau$ of orders $2$, $3$ and $7$ obeying $\rho \sigma \tau=1$. I claim $A_7$ is not so generated. WLOG, $\tau$ must be $(1234567)$. The permutation $\sigma$ must fix a point, WLOG $1$. So $\rho(1) = 7$. In order to be even, $\rho$ is a product of two transpositions, so $\rho = (17) (ab)$. We only have $\tau \rho$ of order $3$ if $(ab)$ is $(25)$ or $(36)$. Both these solutions generate groups of order $168$, not all of $A_7$.

Comment: @Jesse Wolfson: I think the easiest way to find the genus is to use the adjunction formula: for a complete intersection $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ of multidegree $(d_1,\ldots ,d_p)$, the canonical bundle $K_X$ is $\mathcal{O}_X(\sum d_i - n-1)$. Here you find $\mathcal{O}_X(8)$, hence $2g-2=\deg(K_X)= 8\times 2 \times 3\times 4\times 5=960$ and $g=481$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, thanks, that's very helpful!

Comment: Here is another example of a similar spirit to the one @abx suggested.  Consider the sextic Fano 3-fold obtained by setting the first three elementary symmetric polynomials in $\mathbb{P}^6$ to 0, i.e. $V=\{\sigma_1=\sigma_2=\sigma_3=0\}$. Then $S_7$ acts on $V$, and the Fano variety of lines on $V$ is a smooth, irreducible curve $C$ (e.g. by the theorem of Debarre and Manivel).  Since the $S_7$ action on $V$ takes lines to lines, it gives an induced action on the curve $C$.

Comment: That would be a nice example, but you have to prove that your $C$ is smooth — Debarre-Manivel's result is only for a *general* complete intersection.

Comment: Just to report on more nonprogress, I found cases with cycle types (3,3), (3,3) and (4,2), which would give genus $1+|G|/24$ but, again, the group they generate turned out to have order $168$.